# The method showInternalConfirmDialog()is not applicable for the arguments from KeyListener()

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, swing, dialog

I get the error message:

> The method showInternalConfirmDialog(Component, Object, String, int,
>   int) in the type JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (new
>   KeyListener(){}, String, String, int, int)

```
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Key Released F1");
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F1) {



    /*here i get the error*/    int choice = JOptionPane.showInternalConfirmDialog(this, "Would you like to play the movie? " 
                        ,"Message", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE
                        , JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Any idea why I get this error?

Comment: not, not, not, please post an SSCCE, otherwise look at KeyBinding, this one isn't the real question.....

Comment: thx. However I reviewed my question and I think there is everything inside whats needed!

Comment: wrong decision == wrong answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your extending a JFrame, JFrame doesn't extend JComponent. I think this is the reason why it doesn't work. AS a work around I suggest using a JPanel, this code compiled and worked.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CodeTester extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new CodeTester();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);    
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public CodeTester()
    {
        addKeyListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(panel);        
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        int choice = JOptionPane.showInternalConfirmDialog(panel, 
                    "Would you like to play the movie? " 
                       ,"Message", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE
                    , JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);                

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.


**Edited** I've just noticed I coded without the "F1" button condition implemented, I got rid just to simplify.